# 2015年3月29日2時台が無いのは何故？

Tags: php

次のコードを実行してみると、結果は以下のようになります。2015年3月29日の2時台が飛ばされてしまうのは何故でしょうか？

```
$time = mktime(1, 59, 55, 3, 29, 2015);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time + $i);
}
```

2015-03-29 01:59:55
2015-03-29 01:59:56
2015-03-29 01:59:57
2015-03-29 01:59:58
2015-03-29 01:59:59
2015-03-29 03:00:00
2015-03-29 03:00:01
2015-03-29 03:00:02
2015-03-29 03:00:03
2015-03-29 03:00:04

Comment: [ideoneでは再現しませんでした](https://ideone.com/qGnVxY)。動作環境はどのようになっていますか？

Comment: ヨーロッパのサマータイムが考慮されているように見えます。タイムゾーンの設定を見直すか、is_dstパラメータに0を渡す必要があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: おっしゃる通り、タイムゾーンの設定でした。Europe/BerlinをAsia/Tokyoに修正して期待した結果が得られることが確認できました。お二方ともありがとうございました！

Comment: @MasayukiOkubo 自己解決できた場合にはご自身で回答を書いて、その回答を承認していただけると、本質問が解決済みであることが他のユーザによくわかります。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 8):

[quesera2さんコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7579/#comment6828_7579)：

> ヨーロッパのサマータイムが考慮されているように見えます。タイムゾーンの設定を見直すか、is_dstパラメータに0を渡す必要があるのではないでしょうか。